# How to apply multiple textures to GLTF models?

Tags: three.js, textures, gltf

I tried to apply the texture to the model, but it works only in the case of a single texture. With multiple textures, the model is not displayed.

Sample code with a single texture:

```
loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath('models3/');
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('01-Fundament-002.gltf', function (gltf) {
    var model = gltf.scene;
    model.traverse ( ( o ) => {
        if ( o.isMesh ) {
            o.material.map = textureLoader.load('models3/Beton OsnovaVRay-DiffuseShadowMap-Edit.png');
        }
    } );
    scene.add(model);
});
```

Sample code with a multiple texture:

```
loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath('models3/');
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('01-Fundament-002.gltf', function (gltf) {
    var model = gltf.scene;
    model.traverse ( ( o ) => {
        if ( o.isMesh ) {
            const materials = [
                    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load('models3/1.png')}),
                    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load('models3/2.png')}),
                    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load('models3/3.png')}),
                    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load('models3/4.png')}),
                ];

            o.material = materials;
        }
    } );
    scene.add(model);
});
```

Comment: What result do you want to see with these four textures? Are they all partially transparent, and should be stacked on top of one another? Or should different textures apply to different parts of the model?

Comment: Note that once you've loaded a model, it doesn't matter much what format the model was originally. It's just a `THREE.Mesh`, and the usual threejs documentation about materials, decals, and custom shaders all apply. Although one exception is you may want `flipY=false` on the textures: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign an array to the material. I think you are confusing it with [cube texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CubeTexture). This should work assuming your model is made out of 4 meshes only.

```
var i = 1;
loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath('models3/');
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('01-Fundament-002.gltf', function (gltf) {
    var model = gltf.scene;
    model.traverse ( ( o ) => {
        if ( o.isMesh ) {
            o.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(`models3/${i++}.png`)});
        }
    });
    scene.add(model);
});
```